# Connect Multiple Client on Server for Windows Forms Application

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-server-2003, remote-access, terminal-server

We have Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition installed in our server PC. We have deployed our own windows application on Server. Now we need that all the client pc's access it via RDP. But problem is when one user opens it, session of another user automatically gets closed.

I find links saying to use Terminal Server Mode. But I cannot find how to configure all the clients as Termnial users. Is terminal server mode the solution ? If yes, any tutorial to set it up ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: is it a domain environment? it would be straight forward if it were a domain environment, adding the domain users in the list of RDP users and that is it.if not create multiple users on the server for your users and everyone will have their own session and allow maximum number of RDP connections.

Comment: http://www.techspot.com/guides/485-windows-concurrent-sessions/

Comment: @Jaan: We have created 5 users and added to RDP User Group, but only one user can access it at a time.

Comment: @Pranav: We are not having problem creating concurrent sessions, sessions are created, but the application is not allowing concurrent sessions. If one user opens the application, the application of another closes down.

Comment: Start > Administrative Tools > Terminal Services > Terminal Services Configuration.

Comment: Right Click on “Restrict each user to a single session” in the “Edit settings” section and choose “Properties“.

Comment: Uncheck the “Restrict each user to a single session” checkbox and Click OK.

Comment: sorry for the mis-understanding. i thought you have issue with RDP session.

Comment: @Jaan: No it still isn't working.

Comment: a quick workaround would be to rename you application and run it with different instance name for each user. which is / would be a very bad thing to do :). but will give you some ideas as soon as i am done with something on my plate. thanks